# Delete rows from two tables

Tags: sql, cascade, delete-row

I have two tables. Those tables have two relation between them.

```
Table 1
   * ID_XPTO (PK)
   * Detail

Table 2
   * ID_XPTO (FK) (PK)
   * ID_XPTO2 (FK) (PK)
```

Those two relations exists.

```
Table 1 -< Table2 
Table 1 -< Table2
```

My question is that I need to delete some row in table 1. I'm currently doing,

```
declare @table Table (xptoTable2 int)
insert into @table
        select ID_XPTO2
        from Table2 
        where ID_XPTO = @ID_XPTO

delete from Table2
where ID_XPTO = @ID_XPTO

delete from Table
where ID_XPTO in (select xptoTable2from @table)
```

I know that I could use ON DELETE SET NULL on table2. On that way I could then search for all rows with null value on ID_XPTO2 and delete them, but DBA does not wants to use it.

Is there some better solution to do this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have these options:

- Delete in two statements, as you are doing now.  Delete from Table2 first.
- Delete from two tables in one statement, if your brand of database supports multi-table `DELETE` syntax (e.g. MySQL).  This is not standard SQL, but it is handy.
- Use cascading referential integrity constraints (I understand your DBA has nixed this option).
- Write a trigger `BEFORE DELETE` on Table1, to delete or set NULL any reference in Table2.  Check with your DBA to see if this is any more acceptable than the cascading RI constraints.

Finally, I would advise talking to your DBA and asking the same question you asked here.  Find out what solution he/she would prefer you to use.  Folks on StackOverflow can answer technical questions, but it sounds like you are dealing with an **IT policy question**.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ON DELETE CASCADE`. It'll automatically *delete* referencing rows.

Comment: Because DBA does not want to use it. I don't konw why :S

Comment: You said DBA doesn't want SET NULL. I thought he might allow this :) As SET NULL is not the best way to go anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `ON DELETE CASCASE`?

```
DROP TABLE t_f
DROP TABLE t_m
CREATE TABLE t_m (id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY , value VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE t_f (id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, m INT, CONSTRAINT fk_m FOREIGN KEY (m) REFERENCES t_m(id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
INSERT INTO t_m (value) VALUES ('test')
INSERT INTO t_f (m) VALUES (1)
DELETE FROM t_m
SELECT * FROM t_m
SELECT * FROM t_f

id           value
------------ ------
0 rows selected

id           m
------------ ------
0 rows selected
```

Comment: Because DBA does not want to use it. I don't konw why :S

Answer (score 0):

Two methods I know of:

1. You could use ON DELETE CASCADE
2. Write your SQL to clean up after itself ie:

   ```
    DECLARE @DetailCriteria ...

    SET @DetailCriteria = '....'

    BEGIN TRAN
    -- First clear the Table2 of any child records
       DELETE FROM Table2 
       WHERE 
         ID_XPTO IN (SELECT ID_XPTO FROM Table1 WHERE Detail = @DetailCriteria)
         OR ID_XPTO2 IN (SELECT ID_XPTO FROM Table1 WHERE Detail = @DetailCriteria)

    -- Next clear Table2 (which will delete fine because you've followed the referential chain)
       DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Detail = @DetailCriteria

    -- commit if you're happy (should check @@ERROR first)
    COMMIT
   ```